How to encrypt local traffic between WireGuard hosts?
I have a physical server and a virtual server connected via wireguard. The virtual server acts as a gateway to allow remote access to services hosted on the physical server without the need to expose ports.
I have Traefik as a reverse proxy which accepts HTTPS connections and then forwards these requests to the specified WireGuard IP/port combo.
So for example, if a user connects to https://immich.example.com, Traefik will connect them to the physical server hosting immich via its WireGuard address, 10.0.0.5:2283.
The connection from user to reverse proxy is secured by https and the connection from virtual server to physical server is secured by WireGuard.
My concern is the data transferred from the WireGuard endpoint to the reverse proxy within the virtual server. As far as I can tell, this connection is completely unencrypted HTTP traffic. I have concerns as some of this data could be intercepted if an attacker would be to gain access to the virtual server.
What can I do to secure this part of the chain?

Move the TLS terminating reverse proxy to the physical server. On the virtual, run a non-terminating reverse proxy to forward the TLS stream to the physical.

I can't say for sure without more information (like what exactly the service you're trying to expose to the web is), but the solution you seem to be looking for here is SSL/TLS passthrough. Nginx supports it—it passes HTTPS traffic through to the endpoint (the physical server's WireGuard interface, in this case) without decrypting it. If the service you need exposed only supports HTTP, then of course this won't work, however.

Explaining HOW to use SSL/TLS passthrough to solve the question presented will make this an answer. Currently, it is only a comment.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
